# javascript addeventlistener passing the codes to execute for shorter code

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener

Is there a way that I can shorten this code. They have similar condition but different codes to execute. the first one is when I keydown the element will show or hide, the second one after I click the button or submit the form, it will stop or pass the user.

```
textInput.addEventListener("keydown", function myFunction(){
  if(textInput.value.match(characters)){
    invalidFeedback.style.display = "block";
  }
  else if (textInput.value === ""){
    invalidFeedback.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    invalidFeedback.style.display = "none";
  }
});


form.addEventListener("submit", function (event, myFunction){
  if(textInput.value.match(characters)){
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  else if (textInput.value === ""){
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi there John and welcome to SO. If you don't have an issue with your code but are simply looking for feedback, then [codereview.stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be the better platform to ask you question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When multiple conditional statements have the same outcome, we can use the `||` operator, which is like "OR".

We can also export common checks to functions, to keep things granular, neat, and easy-to-consume.

Finally, in the "keydown" event, I introduced a guard clause, which returns the desired outcome on a satisfied condition. It's much easier to read than nested if/else statements.

```js
const doesMatch = () => textInput.value.match(characters);
const isEmpty = () => textInput.value === "";

textInput.addEventListener("keydown", () => {
  if (doesMatch() || isEmpty()) 
    return invalidFeedback.style.display = "block";
  invalidFeedback.style.display = "none"; 
});

form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  if (doesMatch() || isEmpty()) event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Why is it not necessary to return the second invalidFeedback.style.display? what is the logic, I'm new to function.

Comment: @JohnMatt Returning in the first function serves solely to stop the code after it from executing. For the second one, since there is no code that will execute, there's no reason to stop it.